# Visual Studio 2019 Express.js port

Tags: express

I am new to Visual Studio 2019 and am used to VS code. I opened an express.js project in Visual Studio 2019 and every time I ran it the port changes. The default port in the code is port 5000 which does not work when running the code in Visual Studio code. [Random Port opened for the express app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYRv1.png)

Why is it not using the default port?(port:5000).

```
//As defined in bin/www
var port = normalizePort('5000');
app.set('port', port);
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: In SwiftUI the view struct is the view model and you can use enviromentObject in it, you don't need your own view model objects just ignore the MVVM crowd.

Answer (score 0):

When working with "ports" I usually use the "app.listen()" method.

```
var PORT = 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`"the arrow function is optional by the way" server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Try this and I hope it helps.